# Force nginx to send specific Content-Type

Tags: nginx, http-headers, content-type

How to overwrite default Content-Type in nginx? Currently when I request 01.dae file, there's

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
```

And I want it to be

```
Content-Type: application/xml;
```

I tried something like

```
location ~* \.dae$ {
  types { };
  default_type application/xml;
}
```

and

```
location ~* \.dae$ {
  add_header Content-Type application/xml;
}
```

but nothing works.

Comment: The _default_type_ directive should work but you will need to clear the browser's cache or force-reload the content (or "Disable cache" in the Chrome's Developer Tools / Network tab). Otherwise the server will return _304 Not Modified_

Comment: At least with NGINX 1.18.0 there must be no `;` after `types { }`. That would be a parse error. It would be more clear if you write simply `types { } default_type application/xml;` in one line.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can edit `/etc/nginx/mime.types` and add it

```
types {
    application/xml        dae;
}
```

I haven't found the the exact string `application/xml` in my `mime.types` so I suppose you can directly include it inside your server block, in the server scope or something.

If you do not have access to the system `mime.types` then you can set it in the **location** block if you have access to that.
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types

**WARNING** When you set `types` it will overwrite all mime types set in `/etc/nginx/mime.types`. To avoid this target specific extensions with a Regular expression location block. Also know that locations can be nested, like so:

```
server {
    # ...

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html;

        location ~* \.mjs$ {# target only *.mjs files
            # now we can safely override types since we are only
            # targeting a single file extension.
            types {
                text/javascript mjs;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working if the forward-proxied backend server sends its own content-type header.

Answer (score 99):

In case you have no file extension:

```
location ~ something {
   default_type application/xml;
}
```

[Nginx docs for `default_type`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#default_type)

In case you are setting up *let's encrypt certificate with a client which creates http server:* [How to use golang lego let's encrypt client behind nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502926/how-to-use-golang-lego-lets-encrypt-client-behind-nginx)

Comment: If anyone is wondering the `~` instructs nginx to perform a case sensitive regex match, and `something` is the location (or file if you prefer) being matched.

Comment: side note, the default_type setting does not HAVE to sit within a location block. Context can be http, server or location

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#default_type

Comment: But pay attention that spread wide such specific setting WILL lead to many hours of debugging because unclear random issues.

Comment: This is not working for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: @soumitra could you check that your requests match the location?

Comment: Yes, so if I was adding a header, it was working, I could see my test header, but somehow I could not replace the value for an existing header.

Comment: @soumitra could you post `nginx -S` output to somewhere? (pay attention it will contain sensitive information)

Answer (score 4):

```
location ~* \.dae$ {
    types { } default_type "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
}
```

Comment: 2023: this one is the only working solution

Comment: If you want to include a custom charset for a certain filetype this seems to be the only way to do it (I haven't been able to map a charset onto a custom mimetype within a server block).

Answer (score -1):

Add "the application/xml        dae;" to your server scope or location scope.
Or add it into the mime.type.

Both of them work for me.