# MantisBT image preview size setting

Tags: http, nginx, mime, mantis

#### Background:

I'm using Mantis Bug Tracker.

The instance is deployed through Nginx.

It has a very inconvenient property: when we click on a image attachment, like jpg or png.

It pops out to download them.

I guess that's because the returning mime type is not an image.

So I want to affect that through nginx. Please help.

Comment: Have you checked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629930/force-nginx-to-send-specific-content-type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the following options under `config_defaults_inc.php`:

```
$g_preview_image_extensions = array( 'bmp', 'png', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'x-png', 'pjpeg' );
$g_preview_attachments_inline_max_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
$g_preview_max_width = 900;
$g_preview_max_height = 800;
```