# wwwsqldesigner can't perform xlst transformation on Nginx

Tags: xslt, nginx, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to install [wwwsqldesigner](https://github.com/ondras/wwwsqldesigner) and almost succeeded except that generation of sql code doesn't work. When I press `generate SQL` button I get the following error:

`XML error: Failed to execute 'importStylesheet' on 'XSLTProcessor': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

As I understand from [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_xslt_module.html)

> This module is not built by default

But I have a very little experience with Nginx (only few days) so if somebody can help me with a step by step tutorial how to enable **XSLTProcessor** on Nginx it will be great.

This is *.xsl file which used to perform transformation: [output.xsl](https://github.com/ondras/wwwsqldesigner/blob/master/db/postgresql/output.xsl)

Thank you.

Comment: The error you receive is an XML error. You are invoking the processor and the code runs, which means it is (probably) correctly installed. However, it can either not find your stylesheet, it is not proper XML, it does not have proper access rights, or it is not passed as an XML document node. These are just educated guesses, through.

Comment: Or... parameter 1 refers to an actual parameter used in the stylesheet, or used as input XML, in which case the error suggests that it must be a document node as well.

Comment: I've tried to investigate further and took for the reference this site http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/, it seems that on return `xml` document not being parsed/not returned, `xhr.responseXML` upon return is `null`, but `xhr.responseText` is ok. When I parsed manually by `var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "application/xml");` and then injected `xmlDoc` to function which supposed to receive it, it began to work, now I have two options, find out why it doesn't work, or apply this fix as permanent. Thank you for your guess.

Comment: issue was solved, see my answer. Thank you very much for your guesses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mimetype was not registered in the nginx configuration. The issue was solved by adding:

```
types {
    application/xml        xsl;
}
```

to `/nginx/conf/mime.types` file as suggest by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19630564/947111

Comment: Aha, good find! I didn't realize the XSL retrieved could have been the incorrect mime type. Yes, this is a common issue (and can essentially apply to any extension and file type if it wasn't registered before).